How to run scons in the same python process that invoked it?
We have a python program that runs commands using scons. Currently scons runs in a subprocess which make it more difficult to debug or collect test coverage information.
Is it possible to invoke scons such that it runs in the same process of the python program that invokes it?  That is, invoking it as a python function rather than a sub process.

Unless it's written in python and coded to be a callable module, no.

@Barmar SCons is written in python.

https://scons.org/doc/HTML/scons-api/_modules/SCons/Script/Main/ ... OP -- main is there ..

The public API documentation is here

As the project manager for SCons I don't recommend this. It's not supported usage.

The more common model, which is not to say it's the right one for you, is to sort of turn it around: embed the logic from your script in the SCons build configuration; that way it's all in one process - although it's one with SCons in charge. If you head over to the SCons project, there are people who can discuss possible approaches once it's more clear what difficulties you're running into.

Yes, it's possible. SCons is provides importable modules, and the public API documentation can be found here. Scroll down to the Builder Methods section to find the methods that can be called.
And see the source code of the main() program to see how the CLI interface uses the API.
I don't know enough about scons to provide any example code that shows how to use it.

Thanks @Barmer, I will give it a try.
